# Set Bootstrap input value with jQuery ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set two thing with or after the ajax result: The value of this input tag:

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead" name='name'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" />
```

and the `<li>` tags list in this `<ul>`:

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                test label
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="name-dates-dropdown">
                <li>test</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

The idea is this: I get one ajax result list on the #typeahead input tag (this is working well), and if I click on any of the result list, this item is set as the VALUE of this text input and one other ajax request is fired (this is working as well) and the result of this second ajax request (the li list) is set as the new #name-dates-dropdown innerHTML. Sadly none of the setting function is working and I don't know why... :(

I'm using Bootstrap and Bootstrap typeahead.

This is my jQuery function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/functions/name-autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            success: function(data) {
              process(data);
            }
          });
        },
        displayText: function(item) {
            return item
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            $('#typeahead').val(item.value);
            $.ajax({
            url: '/functions/name-dates-autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + item,
            success: function(data) {
              $('#name-dates-dropdown').html(data);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the response sencond ajax call "/functions/name-dates-autocomplete.php" JSON? If yes then how is it formatted. Most likely you have to loop through this JSON Array and Build the HTML by that

Comment: Right now it's not JSON but I can change that quickly on PHP side. Can you please post som example how to loop throw it and add it to the ul list? I'm not really into JS and jQuery. Do you have any idea why the $('#typeahead').val(item.value); is not working as well? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First you got an initialized Plugin the original element might not have been previous capabilities. To set the value of #typeahead use

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead('val', item.value);
```

This is what the API says.

Second if you got json from your second ajax call like this structure

```
// your ajax response
[

    {"value":1,"title":"Whatever"},
    {"value":2,"title":"Whatever 2"},

]
```

then you can loop through it and build the list

```
var listBuilder = '';
$(response).each(function(index, element){

   listBuilder += '<li data-value="' + element.value + '">' + element.title + '</li>';

});

$("#name-dates-dropdown").html(listBuilder);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The <li> list population is working (it's enogh to convert the result to JSON, no listbuilder is required), but $('#typeahead').typeahead('val', item.value); is still not working :( It doesn't set anything :(

Comment: Okay the only thing i found is this document on Github https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadval-val. Maybe try to log item to console and see if the property value is set

Comment: Interesting, because if I put one console output just before it: console.log(item); $('#typeahead').typeahead('val', item); the "item" has the right value... So it must be something with the Bootstrap element or the jQuery command.